# Cast as an NSNumber doubleValue adding extra [phantom] precision

Tags: iphone, sdk, double, nsnumber, number-formatting

iPhone sdk 3.2.1

```
 NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];
 [myDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.1f] forKey:@"testDoubleObject"];
 [myDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.1f] forKey:@"testDoubleValue"];
```

Printing the description of myDict to the console yields this:

Printing description of myDict:
    {type = mutable, count = 2, capacity = 3, pairs = (
     0 : {contents = "testDoubleObject"} = {value = +0.10000000149011611938, type = kCFNumberFloat64Type}
     1 : {contents = "testDoubleValue"} = {value = +0.10000000149011611938, type = kCFNumberFloat64Type}
    )}

Pulling the doubles back out of the dict shows these phantom digits are being preserved:

```
 NSNumber *doubleFromObject = [myDict objectForKey:@"testDoubleObject"];
 NSNumber *doubleFromValue = [myDict valueForKey:@"testDoubleValue"];
```

Printing doubleFromObject and doubleFromValue yields this in the console:

Printing description of doubleFromObject:
{value = +0.10000000149011611938, type = kCFNumberFloat64Type}

Printing description of doubleFromValue:
{value = +0.10000000149011611938, type = kCFNumberFloat64Type}

The same thing happens when I try to create an NSNumber doubleValue from a string:

```
 NSString *doubleAsAString = @"0.1";
 NSNumber *doubleAsANumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[doubleAsAString doubleValue]];
```

Printing doubleAsANumber yields this in the console:

Printing description of doubleAsANumber:
{value = +0.10000000000000000555, type = kCFNumberFloat64Type}

These extra phantom digits are causing me problems.

1) What is causing this to happen?

2) How can I get rid of those extra phantom digits?

Answer (score 3):

**1. What is causing this to happen?**

These "phantom" digits as you say are the by-product of representing a [base-10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal) number in [base-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_2).

**2. How can I get rid of those extra phantom digits?**

The best way to get rid of them would be to use a fixed-precision type, such as [NSDecimal](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/DecimalNumbers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000176-CJBCAGDI).